# changing placeholder text for date field in contact fom7

Tags: wordpress

Creating a contact from in wordpress site i have given placeholder text for date field but still it is displaying as mm/dd/yyyy.How to change this mm/dd/yyyy to Text.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">[date* preferreddate min:2017-01-01 max:2018-12-31 class:c-input class:brd-grey placeholder "Preferred Appointment Date"]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this shortcode because default all date parameters doesn't work. So, your can try to use,

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">[date* placeholder "Preferred Appointment Date"]</div>
```

And Other style manage by css.

Thanks

Comment: just replaced with the code which you have added here

Comment: please check your css file and other source code. you get the error in files

Comment: Example: HTML - <input type="email" placeholder="jane@firefly.com">, CSS - ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}

Comment: Not getting what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this code for palceholder text in contact form7 for date.

```
$('input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"]').each(function() {
var el = this, type = $(el).attr('type');
if ($(el).val() == '') $(el).attr('type', 'text');
$(el).focus(function() {
    $(el).attr('type', type);
    el.click();
});
$(el).blur(function() {
    if ($(el).val() == '') $(el).attr('type', 'text');
});
});
```